# How to find the execution time of a piece of code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, ssms

**C# code**

1. Is it possible find the **execution time** of a set of code in **visual studio**?
2. if **visual studio** does provide any tools for this what are the alternatives?
3. are there any **free** reliable tools to download?

**SQL server management studio**

1. Is it possible find the **execution time** of a set of code in **SQL server Management studio**?
2. if **SQL server Management studio** does provide any tools for this what are the alternatives?
3. are there any **free** reliable tools to download?

thanks

Comment: `SET STATISTICS TIME ON;` - well, that's SSMS sorted...; for .NET code - lots of profilers and instrumenting frameworks exist (I like mini-profiler, but I'm biased; note you can also use mini-profiler to time your SQL code and present all the data together)

Comment: I usually simply create time objects from DateTime.Now on the desired before/after places in the code, then I subtract them and output the resulting TimeSpan as seconds or milliseconds or whatever.

Comment: As an example of what mini-profiler can do, here's a snapshot taken a few moments ago on this very site - note there are lots more steps logged, but they aren't shown by default (see "show trivial"): http://i.stack.imgur.com/PzQkM.png - also provides full access to all the SQL commands that were executed, including their parameters. And we can run it 24x7 in production on stackoverflow.com, it has that little impact

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For SSMS [Query execution time in miliseconds in SQL Server Management Studio](http://code-ninja.blogspot.in/2012/09/query-execution-time-in-miliseconds-in.html)

If you need to get query execution time in milliseconds in SQL Server Management Studio, there is a simple way to achieve this.

```
set statistics time on

-- your query 

set statistics time off
```

This will result in following lin in Messages window:

```
SQL Server Execution Times: CPU time = 16 ms, elapsed time = 16 ms.
```

Answer (score 1):

For C#:

Take a look at **Profiling** Manager in Visual Studio.  It works wonders and solves many of life's programming problems trying to hunt down performance issues.  It's under the Test menu in VS2010.

It can use several different techniques that you can choose from to best suit your performance debugging needs.

For SQL:

I typically just use performance timers, or `DateTime`s.  Used in a stopwatch-like fashion.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to do some quick and dirty timing checks in .NET you can always create a stopwatch then start and stop it around the code in question.  Quick, Free, and Ugly.

Answer (score 0):

For C# if you don't want to use the profiler, and just want to know how long it took for a certain piece of code to execute you can use the stopwatch.

```
var sw = StopWatch.StartNew();
//some code...
sw.Stop();
Console.Writeline(sw.Elapsed);
```

Comment: If you want to be less dirty while still being very dirty, you could create a class out of it that implements `IDisposable` and use it in a `using` statement.

Comment: And why exactly? Just so you can use "Using"? That's not really a good solution and it messes up coding practices, it would be better to use PostSharp AOP and then decorate any method that has to profiled with the right attribute, if you really want to do such things. But don't start creating IDisposable on objects that don't have to be disposed...

Comment: @woutervs What I think aevitas is getting at is that when you implement IDisposable, and therefor use your class in a `using (...)` style, then you can abstract away the Start/Stop calls. This will result in a bit cleaner code since you will only have the using statement left in you own code, and not any specific code to operate your stopwatch.

Comment: I know exactly what he's saying and still in your opinion it may be cleaner, but in most opinions this would never be considered cleaner. Another programmer might think you are using unmanaged resources and so on. If you want to make it cleaner then it's better to use lambda function e.g. Time(()=>YourFunction); Or even better AOP

Comment: Imagine you have to profile 20 different methods using the way you suggested. Also, I can't fathom how you could consider adding the whole PostSharp overhead for this purpose a cleaner solution than creating a small class which takes care of starting/stopping your timer, as well as explicitly marking a section of code as being profiled. I guess you must really like PostSharp.

Comment: Hence my comment about using Lambda's as an alternative, and if you need to profile 20 different methods, I'd suggest using an actual profiler and not writing it in your code. PostSharp is an example and also most known, any AOP solution would do fine. And I still consider it better than marking methods as disposable whilst nothing has to be disposed of.

Comment: The actual use of `IDisposable` has always been subject of wide discussion, I actually consider it to be *alright* to use in two cases: 1. When your object uses unmanaged resources that need to be freed, and 2. When the lifespan of the object is very concise, and you are done with it completely after it has served its small purpose. Of course, the `using` is just shorthand for what you posted, and if you consider `IDisposable` to be something that should only be used when touching unmanaged resources, then that's fine too.